# How to get the value from a Dijit.Calendar?

Tags: javascript, calendar, dojo

This is an easy one, at least I thin it is.

I declared a Dijit.Calendar in my markup and it loads up fine and works.
But I don't understand how I would access the value.

What I want to do is, that a textbox next to the calendar is updated to contain the date the user selected. I don't care if it's updated as soon as the user clicks a date or needs to somehow confirm his selection. I just want an idea on how to achieve this.

Sadly the reference guide doesn't provide any information other than how to set the thing up...

Comment: is this help you? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4922079/how-to-use-dijit-calendar-directly-in-a-form-rather-than-as-a-popup

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Answered by ***dleonardi*** on the dojo IRC.

Basically one connects the `onChange` event to the widget instance, which can be retrieved with `dijit.byId()` (**not** `dojo.byId()`).

The returned instance then simply contains a property called `value`, which is an instance of `Date`.